# Android Studio 2.3 - unknown host "gradle.build.org"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed the Android Studio 2.3 I am facing this problem:

> unknown host "gradle.build.org". You may need to adjust the proxy
>   settings in gradle.

Note: I have already tried to solve the problem by changing the settings from "no proxy" to "auto-detect proxy settings".
But it's still not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you run android studio and open a project it may be that android is downloading these proxy settings as it compiles. I've had a similar problem, if there is a grey/white progress bar at the bottom of the screen, it means gradle is still being built/processed for that project. Simply wait for it to finish.